# convex distance function from a point in CAT(0) space.

Tags: analysis, geometric-group-theory

Let the metric space (X,d) be a CAT(0) space with the metric d. I am trying to 
show that the function $d_p(x)=d(p,x)$ where p is fixed point and x varies is a 
convex function by using the definition of convex function for metric space. 
A function $f:X\rightarrow R$ is said to be convex if for a geodesic $c:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ $f\circ c)$ is convex. If $s\in [0,1]$ the $f(c(s))\leq (1-s)f(c(0)+sf(c(1))$.

By CAT(0) condition $d_p(c(s))\leq \bar d(\bar{p},\bar c(s)) $. If I can show that 
inequality hold for comparison triangle for euclidean case I am done. ($\bar d$ is the euclidean metric in $R^2$).

Comment: I seem to recall that there are many (equivalent) ways to define CAT(0)-spaces, it would be helpful if you could state your favorite.

Comment: After some reconsideration I think that what you are asking may be to show that in the Euclidean plane $\|t\vec b + (1-t)\vec a\| \leq t \|\vec b\| + (1-t)\|\vec a\|$ (which is the triangle inequality) if you use the origin as comparison point for $p$ and the end points of the vectors $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ as comparison for $f(c(0))$ and $f(c(1))$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was foolishly trying writing in coordinate and messing up the calculation.